# How to update fortify rulepack version from (2015.4.0.0008) to (2020.3.0.0009) in linux server where fortify client is installed

Tags: fortify

facing the below error during .fpr file upload.
"Exception: The version of rulepack "HPE Security Fortify Secure Coding Rules, Extended, JSP" in the uploaded scan (2015.4.0.0008) is older than the most recent version of this rulepack for this project version (2020.3.0.0009). Please download the current project file. Open the FPR that you intended to upload in Audit Workbench and migrate it to the downloaded FPR. Save the FPR and upload it again.""

As a workaround i am trying to update the rulepack from (2015.4.0.0008) to (2020.3.0.0009). Can anyone share the steps/wiki to follow for upgrading rulepack on the server where fortify client is installed.